# How to download file with send_file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sendfile

Can someone enlighten me how can I download file with `send_file`?

I have a file `image.jpg` inside `app/assets/images`. I've tried this in my controller:

```
def download
    send_file ("#{Rails.root}/public/images/image.jpg")
end

def download
    send_file ("#{Rails.root}/assets/images/image.jpg")
end

def download
    send_file ("#{Rails.root}/images/image.jpg")
end

def download
    send_file ("/public/images/image.jpg")
end

def download
    send_file ("/assets/public/images/image.jpg")
end

def download
    send_file ("/assets/images/image.jpg")
end
```

For each path it says:

```
ActionController::MissingFile in HomeController#download
Cannot read file 'some_path'
```

What could be a problem here? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
IMAGES_PATH = File.join(Rails.root, "public", "images")

def download
  send_file(File.join(IMAGES_PATH, "image.jpg"))
end
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion but it's the same. Can't find a file.

Comment: You have this error occur even when a image.jpg file exists in the /public/images directory? Maybe try restarting your app server. This should definitely be working.

Answer (score 4):

```
In your view =>
<%= link_to "click here to download", signed_feeds_pdf_path(:feed_image_path => feed_image.feedimage.path), target: '_self' %>

In your controller =>
   def pdf
     file_name = params[:feed_image_path].split('/').last
     @filename ="#{Rails.root}/public/uploads/feed_image/feedimage/#{file_name}"
     send_file(@filename ,
      :type => 'application/pdf/docx/html/htm/doc',
      :disposition => 'attachment')           
  end
soo simple......
```

Answer (score 3):

well, i suggest you to move your file to public folder. Anyway , do this

```
send_file(Rails.root.join('app' , 'assets', 'images', 'image.jpg'))
```

Answer (score 3):

We need to specify the mine type so that it will cache.

```
send_file ("#{Rails.root}/public"+image.image_path), :type => "image/jpeg", :disposition => 'inline'
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still looking for an answer, send_data and send_file won't work when responding to ajax calls. Instead, try submitting a form or using `<a href=..>` to call the controller method and download a file.