# Missing template error even when I added in routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am getting **Missing template posts/download, application/download with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/home/raj/Downloads/carrierwave/app/views"** error while i am running my aplication.

This is my controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
require "tmpdir"
require 'zip'

  TmpDir = "/path/to/tmp/dir"
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

# action method, stream the zip
  def download # silly name but you get the idea
  generate_zip do |zipname, zip_path|
    File.open(zip_path, 'rb') do |zf|
      # you may need to set these to get the file to stream (if you care about that)
      # self.last_modified
      # self.etag
      # self.response.headers['Content-Length']
      self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/zip"
      self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=#{zipname}"
      self.response.body = Enumerator.new do |out| # Enumerator is ruby 1.9
        while !zf.eof? do
          out << zf.read(4096)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end


# Zipfile generator
def generate_zip(&block)
                  invoice = Post.find(params[:post_id])

  photos = invoice.post_attachments
  # base temp File.dirname(__FILE__)
  tmp_dir = Dir.mktmpdir
  # path for zip we are about to create, I find that ruby zip needs to write to a real file
  zip_path = File.join(tmp_dir  , 'export.zip')
  Zip::File::open(zip_path, true) do |zipfile|
    photos.each do |photo|
      zipfile.get_output_stream(photo.avatar.identifier) do |io|
        io.write photo.avatar.file.read
      end
    end
  end
  # yield the zipfile to the action
  block.call 'export.zip', zip_path
ensure
  # clean up the tempdir now!
  FileUtils.rm_rf tmp_dir if tmp_dir
end
```

in routes.rb:

```
get '/posts/download/:post_id' => 'posts#download', as: :download_post
```

and in my index file:

```
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
       <%= link_to "Download", download_post_path(post.id) %>
   <% end %>
```

I also checked in rake routes, i am getting:

```
   download_post GET    /posts/download/:post_id(.:format)   posts#download
```

I don't know where it went wrong. Please help. And I don't want to use a template, it should take with only method.

Comment: There is no view for the  download so its throwing the error

Comment: @SRDP - I don't want view  here, i just want a method where I can download the files.

Comment: In that case just redirect to the original page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this line in your Download action

```
render :nothing => true, :status => 200, :content_type => 'text/html'
```

or redirect to some page

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

An action must render something.....
if it not intended to render anything, you should mention:

```
render :nothing => true
```

Since, here in your case you want this action to provide a file for downloading. I recommend you to go with `send_file` method. It will make your life easy.

Below links will help you with that :

[How to download file with send_file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22002020/1581358)

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_file