# Ruby On Rails: How to check if a csv file is downloaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I have a download button in my view form, which use an "index" action in the controller

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { @some_variables = some_variables.page(params[:page]) }
    format.csv {
      render csv: some_variables, headers: SomeVariable.csv_headers
    }
  end
end
```

And some def self.to_csv method in my model SomeVariable, in which I generate the CSV file.

Is there anyway to check if the download was OK and for example set a flag.
if download went OK
 do something
else
 raise some error
end

I thought about "begin rescue" in a index action, but if there is any other "smarter" implementation sharing it would be more than appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`send_file` can be a good alternative to what you're planning to do.
You can find more information here [How to download file with send_file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22002020/how-to-download-file-with-send-file) and at the [API Dock](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_file)

Comment: Thank you for your comment Stephane.
The download part is already working fine. I'd be looking for a way to check if it goes wrong...

Comment: Then I think that your idea of using a `rescue` is the good one.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a simple solution, I opted for an after_action.
after_action is run only if the action before succeeds, and in this case I'm trying to do something if the download was executed i.e if the csv render get a 202.
So the if the action index is executed after that I run a method for example updating the downloaded time.

```
class SomeVariableController < ApplicationController

after_action :update_downloaded_time, only: :index, if: -> {current_user.admin?}

def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { @some_variables = some_variables.page(params[:page]) }
    format.csv {
      render csv: some_variables, headers: SomeVariable.csv_headers
    }
  end
end

def update_downloaded_time
  @some_varibale.update_all(downloaded_at: Time.now)
end
```